# Detect facebook like outside Page Tab (Mobiles on static URL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Page Tabs for a contest on Facebook. Through the page tab, I can get the signed request to verify if the user has liked the page or not. Mobile cannot access Page Tab so I share one URL (outside FB) that redirects back to the fab is not mobile (and stays on the URL if mobile).

Here is the problem, that way, I can't access signed request (because it's not through a page tab on Facebook) and therefore, have no way to check whether the user has liked the page or not. I though of forcing Facebook Connect prior to entering the contest, but I am not sure if this works great on mobile. Have any good idea to solve this? I must not be the only one facing this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With User Authorization/Login (i think Facebook Connect is a very old term), this would be possible with the `user_likes` permission only. That permission needs to get approved, and you will not get it approved for like gating. Long story short: you have to live without like gates on mobile. I would remove like gates completely, some customers still want them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the `user_likes` permission and then make a API call to the following when the user has logged in (replace the ID with a valid Page ID):

```
me/likes/123456
```

If the user has liked the page, you'll get some information back from Facebook like details of the page and when the user liked it:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "App page", 
      "name": "Your Page Name", 
      "created_time": "2014-01--1T00:00:00+0000", 
      "id": "123456"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    ...
  }
}
```

If the response from Facebook is empty, it means the user hasn't liked the page. E.g.:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

In which case, you then ask the user to Like your page before proceeding to the main area of the app.